# How can we add a dynamic class name in Laravel Collective HTML

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to echo bootstrap class name as "is-invalid" in Laravel Collective HTML **Form::text()** tag if a form input returns any errors  in Laravel

**It reutrns error saying that**

```
"syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING), expecting ']'"
```

**Didn't works in Laravel Collective HTML**

```
 {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control {{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}'] ) !!}
```

**Works in HTML tag**

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" value="">
```

Is there any way to fix this ? Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
{{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => ($errors->has('name')) ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@php
    $class = $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' ;
@endphp
{!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control'. $class] ) !!}
```

Comment: without using {{ }} $errors array object is not reconized as an array

Comment: try it like this then `{!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => "form-control {{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"] ) !!}`

Comment: You cannot use a ternary operator in a string like this.

Comment: ouput comes like this <input class="form-control <?php echo e([]('name') ? ' is-invalid' : ''); ?>" name="name" type="text" id="name" autocomplete="off">

Comment: output : <input class=" is-invalid" name="name" type="text" id="name"> it gives a "is-invalid" class but not "form-control"

Comment: You did it like this `$class = 'form-control'. $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' ;` if yes try the update :p